# How to investigate runlevel initialization?

Tags: ubuntu, init, runlevel

I'm investigating why a service (solr) is not started upon server booting (in this case a vagrant box, running ubuntu 12.04).

The script is running if i run /etc/init.d/solr start

I run sudo update-rc.d solr defaults
But it's not running after booting and i now do not know how to investigate.

What are my debug options?

The script:

```
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          solr
# Required-Start:    $all
# Required-Stop:     $all
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Starts solr
# Description:       Starts solr using start-stop-daemon
### END INIT INFO

SOLR_HOME=/vagrant/solr/jetty
DAEMON=/usr/bin/java
DAEMON_OPTS='-jar start.jar'
NAME=Solr
DESC=Solr
PID_FILE=/vagrant/solr/jetty/$NAME.pid
SOLR_USER=vagrant
SOLR_GROUP=vagrant

test -x $DAEMON || exit 1

set -e

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

case "$1" in
  start)
    echo -n "Starting $DESC: "
    if start-stop-daemon -d $SOLR_HOME --start -b -m --pidfile $PID_FILE --user $SOLR_USER --group $SOLR_GROUP --chuid $SOLR_USER --startas $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_OPTS
    then
        echo "solr started" >> /var/log/messages
        exit 0
    else
    echo "solr start failed" >> /var/log/messages
        exit 1
    fi
    ;;
  stop)
    echo -n "Stopping $DESC: "
    if start-stop-daemon --stop --pidfile $PID_FILE
    then
        echo "stopped."
        exit 0
    else
        echo "failed."
        exit 1
    fi
    ;;
  restart|force-reload)
    ${0} stop
    sleep 0.5
    ${0} start
    ;;
  status)
    status_of_proc -p $PID_FILE "$DAEMON" solr && exit 0 || exit $?
    ;;
  *)
    N=/etc/init.d/$NAME
    echo "Usage: $N {start|stop|restart|force-reload}" >&2
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Output in /var/log/messages is (two times!) `solr started`...

Comment: One thing I might try would be to add a line echo "running start-stop-daemon -d $SOLR_HOME --start -b -m --pidfile $PID_FILE --user $SOLR_USER --group $SOLR_GROUP --chuid $SOLR_USER --startas $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_OPTS" >> /var/log/messages and comparing it when run by hand and run automatically.

Comment: They end up to be exactly the same:

`running start-stop-daemon -d /vagrant/solr/jetty --start -b -m --pidfile /vagrant/solr/jetty/Solr.pid --user vagrant --group vagrant --chuid vagrant --startas /usr/bin/java -- -jar start.jar`

Comment: Could the problem be a difference in environment settings that solr is relying on maybe ?  What if you were to do an "echo "environment file: /tmp/solr-env$$.dump; set > /tmp/solr-env$$.dump" in the startup script and then compare the different resulting environment files?

Comment: I'm not sure what that does, but on startup its `environment file: /tmp/solr-env3188.dump; set` and on manual start it's `environment file: /tmp/solr-env3188.dump; set`

Comment: The key isn't the filename - its the contents.  The "set" command shows the environment variables available to the shell.  If you compare the contents of the file, you may be able to tease out a key setting which is different between the environments - and presumably modify something to compensate.  The number at the end of the file is not important - its simply the process ID - I used it so you would get a different filename each time it was run.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways of resolving this problem, however they will, I suspect, all boil down to the same thing.

The "Crude/Bare metal" way of doing this -  Have a look in /etc  (ideally as root), and you will find a number of directories rcX.d as well as a directory "init.d".

If you look in one of the rcX.d directory you will see it is full of files which are symlinked to /etc/init.d/filename.   The "S" at the beginning of the file means "start".  The number which comes next indicates the order files should be run in.

When the OS initiates/changes runlevel, it runs all the file for that runlevel, ie for runlevel 2 it will run /etc/rc2.d/S*  - If the file is not symlinked in it won't start when the runlevel starts.   To check the current runlevel you can type "runlevel" which will return the currently running runlevel.

You are probably interested in runlevels 2-5 - you can find a list of the runlevels [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runlevel)

If you want to add a program to the appropriate runlevel you can simply create the appropriate symlink.   The way I prefer to do it though is to install "chkconfig".  I don't know if this is a version of the Redhat script (Syntax is not compatible, but very close) - but this command will allow you to view and change what programs work at runlevels.

chkconfig -l  Will show all programs and their runlevels, and chkconfig -l progname will show runlevels enabled for a given program.

To make a program run for a particular runlevel (or multiple runlevels) you can use chkconfig progname Runlevels,   eg chkconfig sshd 2345 will ensure sshd runs when you enter runlevel 2,3,4 or 5.

Comment: As described I run `sudo update-rc.d solr defaults` and it created all entries for me. I'll doublechecked, there are entries like `S20solr -> ../init.d/solr` in all runlevel dirs.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that at the time the init.d scripts are started, `/vagrant/` is not available/mounted but you rely on it being there in your script.

See http://razius.com/articles/launching-services-after-vagrant-mount/ for some pointers.